# How to get time difference between current date time and column value in minutes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table as below

```
user
---------
id
created_on: DATETIME
```

I want to get all the users where the **time difference between the current time and created_on  time must be greater than 30 minutes**.  `(created_on date time - current date time) > 30 minutes`

How to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the MySQL function [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to calculate it for you:

```
SELECT id,
       created_on
  FROM user
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_on, NOW()) > 30
```

**[Live DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04d98/1/0)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE created_on < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [*example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22435852/767881) by [*Prix*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342740/prix),

You can also use `date_sub` or `date_add` on the column with `interval` option.

```
select * from user
where created_on >= date_sub( now(), interval 30 minute);
```

The difference when used with `date_add` shall be negative, e.g. `interval -30 minute`.

There are other date and time functions with which you can get the same result.

**Refer to**:
[MySQL: Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)